# Step up change point detection

Tags: change-point

Can anyone advise me on libraries or code I could use to do `step up change point detection`? By `step up` I mean only step change point detection where the mean increases (see plots bellow).

More info about step detection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection

I done a lot of searching and what I found at best was step change point detection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question (eg, how step detection works), please edit to clarify.

Comment: @gung where would this question be on topic if not here?

Comment: I don't necessarily know. There isn't an SE site for asking for code & packages. Specifically for R, you could try the r-help listserv.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only package that can impose the restriction that the change has to be *positive* (i.e., a step "up") is the `mcp` package: `mcp(list(y ~ 1, ~ 1), df, prior = list(int_2 = "dnorm(0, 10) T(int_1, )")` (Disclaimer: I am the developer)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your pictures it looks like you're talking about change in mean. Standard tests, such as the CUSUM test, should work for this kind of data.

The R package [**changepoint**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=changepoint) should be able to do this. I also have my own package, [**CPAT**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CPAT), that includes the CUSUM test and others that can detect this kind of change.

If you're using **CPAT** the following could work.

```
library(CPAT)

x <- c(rnorm(10, mean = 0), rnorm(90, mean = 2))
# plot(x, type = "l")  # If you want to visualize the data
CUSUM.test(x)  # The CUSUM test
DE.test(x)     # The Darling-Erdös test
HR.test(x)     # The Rényi-type test introduced in a forthcoming paper
```

Comment: I already looked into changepoint and it did not seem to have step up detection.
Does the code you linked do step up detection?

Comment: I tested the code and it does not do step up detection, it does step detection which I explicitly said in the question is not what the question is about. Could you delete the "answer" please or adapt it so that it answers the question? Thank you